# What does `[ EXPRESSION ], [ ] and [OPTION` mean in `man test`?

Tags: test

Examining `man test`, I see that under synopsis for `test` are the possibilities `test EXPRESSION` and `test`.

What does `[ EXPRESSION ], [ ] and [OPTION` mean below ?

Why are the brackets empty and why does `[OPTION` miss a bracket ? Can someone interpret this for me ?

```
NAME
       test - check file types and compare values

SYNOPSIS
       test EXPRESSION
       test

       [ EXPRESSION ]
       [ ]
       [ OPTION
```

Answer (score 11):

`[` is [another name](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) for `test`. All three of those lines are command lines that run `test` with some options.

In the first line, this is standard testing: `[ 5 -gt 4 ]` is the same as `test 5 -gt 4`.

In the second, the expression is omitted, which means to exit false ([`0 arguments: Exit false (1)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)).

For the third case you are, I guess, using GNU coreutils. In GNU `test` the help text contains this note:

> ```
> NOTE: [ honors the --help and --version options, but test does not.
> test treats each of those as it treats any other nonempty STRING.
> ```

This is [a non-POSIX extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils#test-invocation); the motivation seems to be that `test` is required to treat those arguments as strings like any other. `[` is able to distinguish the option case from the string case by the presence of the closing `]` bracket.

Note that your shell will likely provide its own `[`, and so you'll have to `/bin/\[` to use this version.

Answer (score 4):

`[` is the same as `test` as a shell builtin on some shells.

If you look further down `man test`, it describes what are the valid `EXPRESSION` you can test with:

> An omitted EXPRESSION defaults to false.  Otherwise, EXPRESSION is true or false and sets exit status.  It is one of: ...

This may not be apparent to you from the man-page, but in older/some other shells, both `[` and `test` are available as actual commands, which means the space you see in `[ EXPRESSION ]` is *mandatory* for `EXPRESSION` to be accepted as an *argument* for `[`/`test`. Thus, even for shells which offer them as a builtin, they retain this format for compatibility.

<s>And as explained in [@dr01](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/224618/44356)'s answer while I'm typing this, the right square bracket is optional.</s>

Comment: @don_crissti thanks for the heads-up, I think I'll just simply omit that last sentence...

Answer (score 0):

`[ OPTION` is not really missing a bracket.

In fact, perhaps surprisingly, `[` is a command (located in `/usr/bin/[`) equivalent to `test`. 
Therefore it was (at least theoretically) permitted to use just the left bracket, with the right bracket serving just as syntactic sugar. However, [newer shell versions require it](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html).

Comment: Are there other differences between these than `test` cannot be used with an option (not listed with that possibility).

Comment: It is *not* permitted to omit the right bracket, either in POSIX or GNU `[`.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Yes. Corrected.

Comment: I'm not sure what Bash has to do with this...

Comment: @MichaelHomer, in POSIX, the behaviour if you omit the right bracket is not specified, so a POSIX **script** is not permitted to omit the `]`, but a POSIX `[` may do what it wants including calling you names and reboot the machine or print a help message if you call it without it. That allows GNU `grep`'s `[ --version`. `test --version` and `[ --version ]` however are required to return true (test for `--version` being the non-empty string) and output nothing.