# What is the purpose of square bracket executable

Tags: utilities, test

I see there is an executable called "[" in `/usr/bin`. What is its purpose?

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In most cases, `[` is a shell builtin and is equivalent to `test`. However, like `test`, it also exists as a standalone executable: that's the `/bin/[` you saw. You can test this with `type -a [` (on an Arch Linux system, running `bash`):

```
$ type -a [
[ is a shell builtin
[ is /bin/[
```

So, on my system, I have two `[`: my shell's builtin and the executable in `/bin`. The executable is documented in `man test`:

```
TEST(1)                          User Commands                         TEST(1)

NAME
       test - check file types and compare values

SYNOPSIS
       test EXPRESSION
       test

       [ EXPRESSION ]
       [ ]
       [ OPTION

DESCRIPTION
       Exit with the status determined by EXPRESSION.

[ ... ]
```

As you can see in the excerpt of the man page quoted above, `test` and `[` are equivalent. The `/bin/[` and `/bin/test` commands are [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) which is why you'll find them despite the fact that many shells also provide them as builtins. Their presence ensures that constructs like:

```
[ "$var" -gt 10 ]  && echo yes
```

will work even if the shell running them doesn't have a `[` builtin. For example, in `tcsh`:

```
> which [
/sbin/[
> set var = 11
> [ "$var" -gt 10 ]  && echo yes
yes
```

Comment: Well, how is it possible for shell to not have a `[` builtin?

Comment: @AlexandruIrimiea what do you mean? A shell that doesn't have the `[` builtin is just a shell whose authors decided not to add one. `tcsh` [doesn't have](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Builtin_commands.html) a `[` builtin for example.

Comment: OK, now I understand. I didn't know there can be custom shells.

Comment: @AlexandruIrimiea they're not "custom" shells. It's just that `bash` is only one of many programs (shells) that are designed to do similar jobs. Bash is one of the most popular but many systems ship with different default shells. Some of the better known ones are `sh`, `bash`, `zsh`, `dash`, `ksh`, `tcsh`, `csh` and `fish`. You can see the ones available on your system with `cat /etc/shells` and a partial list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_command_shells).

Comment: @AlexandruIrimiea: considering that your screenshot looks very Ubuntu-y, you are already using at least two different shells: the default shell for scripts on Ubuntu is `dash`, `bash` is only the default for interactive logins, and if for some reason your boot fails early on, or you do a non-standard installation, you will be dropped into `ash` (or more precisely the BusyBox implementation of it).

Comment: @JörgWMittag really? I knew that Ubuntu's `sh` is `dash` but I thought the rescue system uses `/bin/sh` not busybox. Are you sure?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I just checked on an Ubuntu box and there's no `busybox` installed by default. What you describe might (I haven't checked) happen during installation but not on failed boot. Since there's no `busybox` installed, it's safe to assume that the rescue shell will be `/bin/sh`, so `dash` on Ubuntu.

Comment: Hmm … I think it's in the initramfs, so it wouldn't be installed on the system. But I could very well be misremembering and it's only in the netinstaller, or maybe it's Debian, not Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm an Ubuntu user, I've also a VM of 15.10 Ubuntu , which I booted just now (because I'm lazy to reboot). The default root shell in recovery is `/bin/bash` (since recovery shell is still interactive).

Comment: However, there is indeed a busybox in initramfs, as evidenced from this [question](http://askubuntu.com/q/137655/295286)

Comment: @AlexandruIrimiea, regarding what commands it is *necessary* to have built in and what commands may or may not be built in, see [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11460/135943).

Comment: @AlexandruIrimiea, one of the fun facts on Unix is that the program with with the user usually interacts directly is just a plain, run-of-the-mill program. And not even one very hard to write, at least in simple incarnations (writing a simple shell is a popular homework assignment). As a result, everybody and aunt Tillie wrote their own, and there is a veritable plethora to select from. `sh` (the "original" Bourne shell) is mandated to be available by POSIX, there are truly exotic shells around as alternatives.

Answer (score 12):

That is used for condition testing in shell scripts. Another name of this program is `test`:

```
if [ 1 -lt 2 ]; then ...
```

That looks like shell grammar but isn't. Usually `[` is a shell builtin but probably as fallback it exists as an external command.

See the block "CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS" in `man bash`.

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224616/what-does-expression-and-option-mean-in-man-test

Answer (score 9):

`[` is same command as `test`. On some *nix systems, one is just a link to the other. For example, if you run:

```
strings /usr/bin/test 
strings /usr/bin/[
```

you will see the same output.

Most sh-shells/posix-shells include builtin `[` and `test` commands.
The same is true for `echo`. There is both a `/bin/echo` command and a
builtin in most of shells. That it's the reason why sometimes you feel that, for example, `echo` doesn't work the same way on different systems.

`test` or `[` return only an exit code of `0` or `1`. If the test was successful, the exit code is 0.

```
# you can use [ command but last argument must be ] 
# = inside joke for programmers 
# or use test command. Args are same, but last arg can't be ] :)
# so you can't write 
#    [-f file.txt] because [-f is not command and last argument is not ]
# after [ have to be delimiter as after every commands
[ -f file.txt ] && echo "file exists" || echo "file does not exist"
test -f file.txt && echo "file exists" || echo "file does not exist"
[ 1 -gt 2 ] && echo yes || echo no
test 1 -gt 2  && echo yes || echo no
# use external command, not builtin
/usr/bin/[ 1 -gt 2 ] && echo yes || echo no
```

You can also use `[` with `if`:

```
if [ -f file.txt ] ; then
  echo "file exists" 
else 
  echo "file does not exist"
fi
# is the same as
if test -f file.txt  ; then
  echo "file exists" 
else 
  echo "file does not exist"
fi
```

But you can use `if` with every command, `if` is for testing exit code. 
For example:

```
cp x y 2>/dev/null && echo cp x y OK ||  echo cp x y not OK
```

Or, using `if`:

```
if cp x y 2>/dev/null ; then
   echo cp x y OK
else
   echo cp x y not OK
fi
```

You can get the same result using only the `test` command to test the exit code which is saved to the variable `stat`:

```
cp x y 2>/dev/null 
stat=$?
if test "$stat" = 0 ; then
   echo cp x y OK
else
   echo cp x y not OK
fi
```

You can also use `[[ ]]` and `(( ))` for testing, but those are not the same as `[` and `test`, despite having almost the same syntax:

Finally, to find out what a command is, you can use:

```
type -a command
```

Comment: For comparing files you should rather use `cmp /usr/bin/[ /usr/bin/test` or maybe hashes `sha256sum /usr/bin/[ /usr/bin/test` but not `strings`. On my system (openSUSE Tumbleweed) BTW they are not the same (whyever).

Comment: I didn't mean byte comparing. In some *nix they are same also in byte level = linked.  [Posix test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)