# bash - What do the brackets in if-statements do?

Tags: linux, bash, test, control-flow

Perhaps this applies to more than just bash, but I am confused about the role of brackets in if-statements. Most [examples](http://bencane.com/2014/01/27/8-examples-of-bash-if-statements-to-get-you-started/) seem to have the following format

```
if [ expression ]; then
    #do stuff
fi
```

But this doesn't always work for me. For example I have the following script `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

flag=False
if ! $flag; then
    echo "No brackets: Flag is $flag"
fi
if [ ! $flag ]; then
    echo "With brackets: Flag is $flag"
fi
echo "The end."
```

Which prints

```
$ ./test.sh
No brackets: Flag is False
The end.
```

So the statement using brackets is either ignored or it evaluates to False. Why does this happen? What do the brackets do?

I've also seen double brackets. How are those used?

--

Edit: the questions claimed as duplicates ([this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224616/what-does-expression-and-option-mean-in-man-test) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99185/what-do-square-brackets-mean-without-the-if-on-the-left)) answer only a small part of this question. I'm still unclear why the syntax with brackets would fail (it seems to me that `test ! false` should evaluate to `true`) and why the syntax without brackets succeeds (although, as @ilkkachu mentions in the comment, it seems like it should actually fail as well?).

Comment: Or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99185/what-do-square-brackets-mean-without-the-if-on-the-left

Comment: This could be a good reference for you to read over.  https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/conditions-in-bash-scripting-if-statements/

Comment: `flag=False; if ! $flag ; then ...` should give you an error, unless you really have a command called `False`. (`false` would be standard, however)

Comment: ... for me `if [ !$flag ]; then` works (no space between `!` and `$flag`)

Comment: I have googled that if test have 2 arguments and If the first argument is ! (exclamation mark), the expression is true if, and only if, the second argument is null. i found it [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest)

Comment: @ilkkachu They may be running macOS on a case-insensitive filesystem.

Comment: @Kusalananda, yeah, thanks for reminding me of that horror, I was happy to have forgotten that. (The joke here is that it's a Mac I have on my lap right now, and `False` and "True" work just fine. *rolleyes*)

Answer (score 4):

On any Unix other than those that have case-insensitive filesystems (like macOS), the `if` statement

```
if ! $flag; then
    echo "No brackets: Flag is $flag"
fi
```

would generate the output

```
bash: False: command not found
No brackets: Flag is False
```

On macOS, the error would not be generate as the `False` command is the same as the standard (external) `false` command due to the case-insensitivity of the filesystem.

In either case, the test on `! $flag` is true (but for different reasons), so the text is printed.  On most Unices, `! $flag` is true since it runs the `False` command, fails, and the failure is negated.  On macOS, it runs the external `false` utility, which returns false, which is negated.

The second `if` statement,

```
if [ ! $flag ]; then
    echo "With brackets: Flag is $flag"
fi
```

works the same way on any Unix.  It calls the `[` utility, which is the same as the `test` utility (but `[` requires a matching `]` as its last operand), with the two arguments `!` and `False`.  By default, `test` will return a true value if the string argument has non-zero length, which it has, but it's negated by the `!` so `test` returns false and the `echo` is never executed.

For clarity, it is better to use the `-n` test to test for a non-empty string:

```
if [ -n "$flag" ]; then ...
```

or `-z` to test for an empty string:

```
if [ -z "$flag" ]; then ...
```

The quoting of the variable expansions is not important in this particular piece of code as `$flag` expands to a single word that is not a filename globbing pattern.  In general though, variable expansions should be double quoted to avoid word splitting and filename globbing.

For a discussion about `[` vs. `[[`, see

- [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111)

Related:

- `man test` on your system, and `help test` in any `bash` shell.
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)

Comment: @Christopher Hmm... My main disk is still case-insensitive with APFS, but that may be because it's been converted from case-insensitive HFS+ with the Mojave update. BTW, HFS+ had a case-sensitive option too, but the default was case-insensitive.

Comment: Whether `$flag` expand to one or more words and which depends on the value of `$IFS`. It still doesn't make sense to leave it unquoted when you know `$flag` contains `False`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Bash resets `IFS` for new shells, and the variable is not set in the script. How could `$flag` be split in multiple words here?

Comment: Yes, it may be OK if that script in its entirety is not modified or that code is not copy pasted elsewhere (but now it's on a Q&A website, so it's too late) and that script is not sourced. Those are the conditions we'd need to state to say it may be acceptable not to quote. Why would you not quote though?

Answer (score 2):

The exact answer is a bit complex. It boils down to understanding that the word `false` is both a command and an string (depending on context).

A longer description:

Lets start with the string *A_Non_Existing_Command*.

```
str=A_Non_Existing_Command
```

So, a (In general: please quote variable expansions.)

```
$ if $str; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
bash: A_Non_Existing_Command: command not found
no
```

Will print *no*, as the command executed fails (it doesn't exist) and the else part gets executed. Of course, there is an error message as well (more later).

However, the test command, either `test` or `[` (read `help test` inside bash) will test if:

> the length of the string between brackets is non-zero

And, so:

```
$ if [ "$str" ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
yes
```

Prints a yes (as the string has a non-zero amount of characters (usually bytes)). It doesn't matter that the string is also the name of a non-existing command. In this case the value of the variable is interpreted (evaluated) as an string.

And, of course, the negative test will print no:

```
$ if [ ! "$str" ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
no
```

Which is exactly equivalent to `[ -z "$str" ]`.

Now, changing the `str` content to `False` and executing the same commands:

```
 $ str=false
 $ if     "$str"  ; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
 no

 $ if [   "$str" ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
 yes

 $ if [ ! "$str" ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
 no
```

If you get the same with `str=False` (without errors) is probably because you are in a system with a case-insensitive filesystem (where searching for False will find false without any error).